# Swift - Parse Check if PFFile is cached

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform, pfimageview

Considering I'm using PFImageViews, with caching enabled, I would like to know if there's a way to determine whether an image has already been downloaded or not.

All in all, I want to say:

```
if imageAlreadyDownloaded {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: If you are planning to use it , please read before starting to implement it. shutdown by Jan 28, 2017.  http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/..

Comment: @andyPaul Thank you, but I knew that... I forgot to mention, I have my own Parse Server.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally found the solution to my own problem! Every PFFile, has a boolean property called "isDataAvailable".

With a bit of code we can have the following solution:

```
let imageFile = file as? PFFile

if imageFile.isDataAvailable {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

And done! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to roll your own solution using the PFImageView and the loadInBackground method that has a completion handler.

Something like:

```
// Instance property on your UIViewController
private var imageAlreadyDownloaded = false

// Somewhere else in your UIViewController...
imageView.loadInBackground() { 
    [unowned self] (image, error) in

    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }
    self.imageAlreadyDownloaded = true
}
```

Comment: In that case, I think the image would be downloaded in both cases, which I want to prevent.. Right?

Comment: My intention was that this code would be called once, when you initiate your download. I did not intend for `loadInTheBackground` to be called twice. That said, it seems you found another good solution.